# OpenMP poor performance

Tags: c, matrix, parallel-processing, openmp

I have this issue, I wrote an OpenMP program which has to calculate the products of `m` matrices. I want to give to each thread `N` rows to process.

This is my code:

```
double val;
    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    for(i=0;i<m;i++){
        #pragma omp parallel for private(f,c,k)
        for(f=0;f<N;f++){ //cada thread trabaja con sus 2 filas asignadas
            //printf("Thread %d, fila %d matriz %d \n",omp_get_thread_num(),f,i);
            for(c=0;c<N;c++){ //cada fila trabaja con todas las columnas de la matriz principal
                val=0;
                for(k=0;k<N;k++){
                    /*if(k==0){
                        AUX[f*N+c]=RES[f*N+k]*A[i][k*N+c];
                    }*/
                    //else{
                        AUX[f*N+c]=val+RES[f*N+k]*A[i][k*N+c];
                    val=AUX[f*N+c];

                    //}
                }
            }
           for(c=0;c<N;c++){
                RES[f*N+c]=AUX[f*N+c];
            }
        }
    }
```

The result is OK, but in performance a sequential algorithm is better...

I also made  a Pthread solution and it works fine so I think I have some mistake when I parallelized the solution...

Comment: reverse the order of the k and c loop

Comment: Hi @user3528438 what do you mean?

Comment: re-arrange `for(c=0;c<N;c++)` to be the inner-most loop

Comment: Optimizing compilers may skip more redundant loops in the absence of openmp.

Comment: If you're trying to maximize performance quickly you would use one of the available libraries such as mkl

Comment: I think `val` should be private.

Comment: I'm afraid your code is a mess and much needed information is missing in this question. Please 1) Provide information about the expected and actual performance 2) Provide information about the hardware and configuration, 3) Provide a [mcve] and format it properly, with relevant comments in english language and remove redundant comments.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution!, first, I didn't pay attention to the way I stored the data into the matrixes, and I had a lot of cache fails. So the RES Matrix stored by rows and the others by column.

Also, i put private the "val" variable. and the performance was improved.